# How to make the default UI elements in Qt more beautiful?

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning to use Qt & currently able to develop an Application with most of the widgets in their standard format. Now I want to make my widgets more beautiful. The standard one's are very dull for Windows. I would like to know which properties of widget's are normally used to change their appearance.
For example, the standard `QPushButton` doesn't have a *glassy* appearance as can be observed in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EBXd8xS0IRk) video. Please observe the feel of the button's at 0:10 (10 secs after starting the video).
[Here](http://www.pdfarchitect.org/images/screenshots/combine.png)'s another example. The up & down button's & the button's below.
How do I do such editing in Qt?
Please note that I do not want to copy the UI, just want to know how to create such beautiful widgets?
Any help on this topic would be very helpful for me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the `QStyle` class http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyle.html

Comment: Thanks for that.
But do you know any article or some tutorial which explains how to use it?
It seems pretty big & difficult to me at first look.

Comment: If you wand to use one of existing styles you could do
`QApplication::setStyle(new QWindowsStyle);`
with the style you need. I f you want customize appearence, I think it would be easy to use stylesheets

Comment: ok, but do you know any tutorial for the style sheets?
I am a beginner in GUI programming as such.

Answer (score 4):

QStyle is one option, the other one is to edit the Stylesheet of a single component, In Qt Designer, you can open  item's CSS sheet.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html

Comment: AFAIK, CSS is some sort of a scripting language used in developing web pages. Can deal with QStyle without CSS?
Thanks for the link it seems very informative.
Know any video tutorial on YouTube regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just started to learn Qt and you are not constrained to QWidget-style Qt by some Big Boss I'd recommend you to learn [Qt QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html) because it is the future of Qt while QWidgets+stylesheets are becoming obsolete. Moreover it is much more simple to program against declarative QML than deal with buggy stylesheets.

Comment: on first look it looks quite impressive.
Thank You for the answer.